# Angular ng-repeat with filter not updating with http.get

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-filter

I am filtering an array (*results*) with a query. By removing the filter, *results* accurately displays all elements. By removing the http.get that updates *results* and initializing *results* to contain elements, the filter accurately filters.

With both the filter and the http.get updating *results*, the message for no results is showing even when **results** contains data. I have verified that **results** is properly updated by the http.get (as evidenced by *{{results}}* showing correctly below). The following is what *{{results}}* displays:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Company Number 1 ",
    "description": "description of 1 "
  },
  {
    "name": "Company Number 1 ",
    "description": "description of 1 "
  },
  {
    "name": "Company Number 2 ",
    "description": "description of 2 "
  }
]
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="form-group label-floating">
    <label class="control-label" for="addon1">Filter</label>
    <input id="addon1" class="form-control" type="text" data-ng-model="query">
</div>

{{results}} <!--This works properly-->

<table class="table table-striped" id="resultsTable">
    <tbody>
    <tr data-ng-show="resultsFilter.length === 0">
        <td class="center" colspan="3">No results found.</td> <!--This message appears even when results should have elements-->
    </tr>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="result in resultsFilter = (results | filter:query | limitTo:displayNum) track by result.name">
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                {{result.name}}
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**angular.js**

```
$scope.query = "";
$scope.displayNum = 20;
$scope.results = [];
...
$scope.updateResults = function () {
    $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: requestUrl,
    params: {id: $scope.identifierInHierarchy.companyId}
})
    .then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.query = "";
        $scope.results = [];
        response.data.forEach(function (entry) {
            $scope.results.push({
                name: "Company Number " + entry.CompanyNumber,
                description: "description of " + entry.CompanyNumber
            });
        });
    },
        function errorCallback(response) {
        });
}
```

Update: No, changing resultsFilter to results does not resolve the issue. I also believe it is not incorrect since keeping resultsFilter and initializing results statically will filter correctly (as previously stated).

Comment: Where do you declare resultsFilter?

Comment: It is not declared (or somehow declared simultaneously with its assignment, I'm not sure). However, the filtering works when results is not updated with the GET. Just to be thorough, I added a declaration $scope.resultsFilter = [] after the declaration of results, but this actually led to the "no results" message showing simultaneously with the results (when results is not updated with GET). With GET, there was no change and only the no results was shown.

Comment: I found the resource (and reasoning) I used to create the resultsFilter: http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/08/tip-accessing-filtered-array-outside-ng-repeat/

Answer (score 0):

You are using `resultsFilter` everywhere which is no where declared. It should be `results`.

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="resultsTable">
<tbody>
<tr data-ng-show="{{results.length}} === 0">
    <td class="center" colspan="3">No results found.</td> <!--This message appears even when results should have elements-->
</tr>
<tr data-ng-repeat="result in results = (results | filter:query | limitTo:displayNum) track by result.name">
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
            {{result.name}}
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: No, changing resultsFilter to results does not resolve the issue. I also believe it is not incorrect since keeping resultsFilter and initializing results statically will filter correctly (as previously stated).

Comment: You are missing angular expression symbol `{{}}` around `data-ng-show="results.length ===0`. Check it. `results.length` should be `{{results.length}}`.

Comment: As is, the filtering works when not using GET to update results. By adding {{}}, the filtering did not work with or without GET.

Answer (score 0):

It's showing no result because of this

```
<tr data-ng-show="resultsFilter.length === 0">
        <td class="center" colspan="3">No results found.</td> <!--This message appears even when results should have elements-->
    </tr>
```

**resultsFilter** scope is limited to ng-repeat and you are trying to access it above scope. so Please change it only with results and then test it.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Attempted this solution; was not successful. Also, it does not seem to be an issue when initializing results statically and not using GET.